# What are the methods access sqlite db directly from bundle path in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, ipad, sqlite

Is it ok to access sqlite db directly from bundle path OR Copy sqlite db from bundle to  documentary path and then access sqlite db? 
Which is efficient method? Can anyone please suggest me on this?

Comment: I don't want to change the records in database. I just want to read the data from data base. So should i need to copy the database from bundle to documents directory? and can i directly open database in bundle itself as many times i want?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the files that are in bundle. If you need to change in the database you need to copy it in Documents directory. but if the database is not being changed you may keep it in bundle. But it is convention that people create copy of database in Documents directory.

Change in database = manipulate records of database.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu :)    I don't want to change the records in database. I just want to read the data from data base. So should i need to copy the database from bundle to documents directory? and can i directly open database in bundle itself as many times i want?

Comment: As far as i know it would increase communication overhead, as it will have to face some internal OS api calls. but to answer your question you can directly open database in bundle itself as many times you want.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to copy the DB to the Library or document Directory, and make all the process from the locally saved database in document or library folder.

I prefer to keep it to library folder such that user can not open and delete it , just for safety.
If u access the DB from the Main bundle you can have a problem, further if you upgrade the app version and want to make changes to your DB.

So, better option is to keep the DB to Document or library folder and access it from there.

Hope it makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access or read the DB data directly from the documents directory,

1. You have to copy the DB to documents directory programmatically and then you can use the below code to access the DB (Select,Update,Delete operations).

   ```
   NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XYZ.sqlite"];


   BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];

   if(fileExists)
   {
    if (foofile)
    {
      myText = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:foofile];    
      if (myText)
      {
       [self start];
      }
      else{;}      
    }
   }
   else
   {
     NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XYZ" 
                                                          ofType:@"sqlite"];
     if (filePath)
     {  
      myText = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];    
      if (myText)
      {
         [self start];
      }
      else
      {;}      
     }
    }
   ```